# How do I solve this sum of series problem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm studying for a test, I chose a random question and this one came out. How do I solve it? What does it do? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Follow the instruction and proceed. Find the representation of $1/(1-x)$ which very common.

Comment: Where did you run into trouble applying the extremely detailed instructions in your question?

Comment: I didnt know the geometric series way of 1/(1-x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question basically gives you the steps on how to solve for the sum.
Start with $1/(1-x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +......  $
Differentiate: $$[1/(1-x)]' = 1/(1-x)^2 = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 +.... $$
Multiply by x:$$x/(1-x)^2 = x+ 2x^2 + 3x^3 + ..... $$
Differentiate again:$$[x/(1-x)^2]' = (1+x)/(1-x)^3 = 1 + 4x + 9x^2 + 16x^3 +..... $$
Multiply by x again:$$x(1+x)/(1-x)^3 = x + 4x^2 + 9x^3 + 16x^4 +..... $$
So when $x = \frac12$, $\frac12(1+\frac12)/(1-\frac12)^3=6$

Comment: Thanks! I know, but I didnt know the 1/(1-x) as a geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Write the series as $$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n(n-1)+n) x^n=x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1) x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^{n-1}$$ So $$S=x^2\Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty  x^{n}\Big)''+x\Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty  x^{n}\Big)'$$ I am sure that you can take it from here. When you finish, make $x=\frac 12$.